# How to understand that value of C++ class member variable is not consistent in destructor function

Tags: c++, destructor

I write a demo to test dustructor behavior, and the output result is not as expected. Can anyone tell me why?

The source code is as follow:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <cstdlib>
    using namespace std;
    class Str{
    private:
        char *pstr;
    public:
        Str(char value[])
        {
            cout<<this<<":constructor called"<<endl;
            pstr = NULL;
            int len = strlen(value);
            pstr = (char *)malloc(len + 1);
            memset(pstr,0,len + 1);
            strcpy(pstr,value);
        }
        ~Str()
        {
            cout<<this<<":destructor called, "<<(long)pstr<<endl;
            if(pstr != NULL)
            {
                cout<<this<<":destructor call free() "<<endl;
                free(pstr);
                pstr = NULL;
            }
        }
    };
    int main()
    {
        Str *p = new Str("aaa");
        delete p;
        delete p; //make destuctor called twice.
        return 0; 
    }
```

The output of the program is as folows:

```html
0x600001240040:constructor called
0x600001240040:destructor called, 105553135403088
0x600001240040:destructor call free()
0x600001240040:destructor called, 255133788340288
0x600001240040:destructor call free()
a.out(71425,0x1fdc8e080) malloc: *** error for object 0xe80af6d30040: pointer being freed was not allocated
a.out(71425,0x1fdc8e080) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

Look at the output, why the member variable "pstr" is not null for the second calling of destructor?

It was obviously asigned null in the first calling of destructor.

Comment: Calling `delete` twice is undefined behaviour, e.g. compiler is free to remove `pstr=NULL` as unnecessary write because the user can never read this value.

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.  The memory is likely overwritten after calling the first `delete`

Comment: the second `delete p;` is undefined behavior. There is no longer an object whose destructor you could call or whose member has some value, you already destroyed it.

Comment: _"why the member variable "pstr" is not null for the second calling of destructor"_ - It's `p` that's not null and it's not null because you never assigned null to it.

Comment: To avoid the undefined behavior, use this for the first delete: `delete std::exchange(p, nullptr);`

Comment: @Eljay: There's generally no need for that. Almost every use of `delete` is in a destructor, and you can't access object members afterwards, so setting those object members to `nullptr` does not achieve anything.

Comment: @MSalters • calling `delete p; delete p;` is undefined behavior for the second delete.  Setting the `p` to `nullptr` after the first `delete` protects against the undefined behavior.  In the general case, when there may be lengthy separation in the code or processing between the two deletes of the same pointer variable.  But these days, it'd be better to use an owning smart pointer, like `std::unique_ptr` to avoid this unpleasant situation altogether.

Comment: Incidentally, that call to `memset` before `strcpy` is pointless. `strcpy` can copy into raw memory.

Comment: @Eljay: There should not be a "lengthy separation". `delete` should be restricted to destructors of classes owning a single resource, so that destructor will be quite short. (The reason for this rule is that exception handling calls destructors for fully constructed sub-objects, there is no good way to handle the case where one dtor needs to delete one of two managed resources)

Comment: "C++ `new` is the flame, raw memory pointer is the fuse, using a dangling memory pointer after `delete` is the bomb." — Dragnet (paraphrased)

Comment: @MSalters • there is no class that owns `Str *p`.  It's in `main`.

Comment: @Eljay: That is exactly the problem. There  **should** be a class that owns the object, e.g. `std::unique_ptr<Str>`.

Comment: @MSalters • Agreed!  The OP's example is a good demonstration why an unmanaged resource (a raw pointer) is dangerous.  C++ already has enough footguns as-is, no need to voluntarily don more.